# Linux C | How can we redirect printf to syslog?

Tags: linux, logs, c, syslog, printf

We are using printf till now and the output was coming to stdio. Now we want to remove it from stdio and put in syslog.

I have a big code base and so replacing all the printf will not be a good approach.

Some ideas are to use freopen() or dup()/dup2() but I am not fully assured about these.

Anyone have idea how can we archive this?

Comment: I presume you get valid reasons for hardcoding this change (vs leave the decision to the user)

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to change `stdout`¹ to a pipe to `logger` which would do the heavy lifting of formatting the log messages and sending them to syslog:

```c
char cmd[64];
sprintf(cmd, "logger -t your-program -p daemon.info --id=%d", getpid());
stdout = popen(cmd, "w");
setlinebuf(stdout);
```

(error handling left as an exercise)

Or not modify your program at all but run it as:

```bash
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec stdbuf -oL your-program' |
  (
    IFS= read -r pid &&
      exec logger -p daemon.info -t your-program --id="$pid"
  )
```

Note that in that case, it's all the output by `your-program` and its children that gets redirected to `logger`, including when not done via the stdio API (like with direct `write(1, data, length)`, and assuming fd 1 has not otherwise been redirected to something else).

`-oL` tries to achieve the equivalent of `setlinebuf(stdout)` above by injecting that code into the executables. That won't have an effect if you-program (or any other program it calls which would also be affected) otherwise calls `setvbuf()` or is not dynamically linked, or is setuid/setgid...

---

<sup>¹ the stdio `FILE*` object, not the actual stdout / fd 1 here, so if ever your-program executes other commands in child processes they won't be affected.</sup>

Comment: Also warning that for OP's programs running as daemons on a systemd-ized system this code is at least useless since stdout & stderr are automagically redirected to the journal.

Comment: @MC68020, that `program | logger` produces no output, so I'd expect if that's what `systemd` starts, it would redirect nothing to the journal.